# Как вычислить неопределённый интеграл на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, математика

Мне нужна библиотека (js), которая может найти первообразную функции, которую я передаю как строку. 

Например:

`integrate("x") //возвращает (1/2)*x^2`

Я нашёл несколько библиотек, которые могут это сделать. Например nerdamer, algebrite, newton-lib и подобное.

Но проблема всех этих библиотек, что они не могут корректно работать со сложными функциями, такими как:
3*sin(2*x)*cos(x)^4 
3*sin(2*x)*sin(x)^4 

(5*(ln(5*x))^4)/x

При этом есть куча онлайн сервисов, которые способны работать и со сложными функция. 
Например: 
 https://www.wolframalpha.com/calculators/integral-calculator/ 
https://math24.biz/integral 
https://math.semestr.ru/math/int.php
http://maxima.cesga.es/index.php?c=hnhv2ra5cen4jb6x0pmyp&n=1 и подобное

Есть ли всё-таки библиотека (желательно на js), которая способна работать со сложными функциями и выдавать то, что выдают эти онлайн-сервисы?

Comment: В ваших ссылках вычисления происходят на сервере. Это скорее всего и не JS )

Comment: да, я даже посмотрел, некоторые из них используют систему maxima, но она написана на незнакомом лично мне ЯП(